# How to save data without triggering an event

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a quiz where I want to save all attempted/unattempted questions. So that in-case the user has answered half, and for some reason he gets logged out, then he does not have to begin from first the next time he logs in.

Can someone help me with this?
I am developing this project in PHP.

Comment: You can make AJAX call when user submits any answer to any question. Doing this you will have all the questions attempted by the user with given answers

Comment: use a timer(setinterval)  and set your form-data using localstorage/cookies if needs to be on server use ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions.
These helped me find the actual way that was suitable for my project.

I opted a different option for this.
What I did is called an ajax to save the records whenever there was a radio button trigger event.

This is saving me the random triggers that I would have set in intervals.
Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to send automatic [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to the server and make an auto save behavior.

The other way is to use [`localSotrage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) without any interaction with the server.

If you would have provided some code, it would have been easier to demonstrate suggestions by adapting your example.

Comment: Your suggestion is quite helpful. I cannot share the code snippet here because it wouldn't relate to the query I have.

Answer (score 0):

**Lazarev* Alexandr* gave very nice suggestion you can use localstorage
but if you are not comfortable with localstorage or your client in older browser that can not support localstorage. then you can use ajax request in every everytime user attempted the question you can request to server and store user answer and if he change one of the attempted question you can update in server..

Comment: I cannot access localstorage in PHP. I as it is have to send it via javascript ajax.